# Remove all repeatable values from the list and the values that are inside other values, Python

Tags: python, list

My list contains of sentences. There are sentences that can be repeated and there are sentences that are inside some other sentences. For example:

1. 'Heterocyclic compounds'
2. 'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen'

Number 1 is inside number 2 so I need to keep only unique one that is number 2.

Part of my list:

```
    ['HUMAN NECESSITIES',
     'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
     'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
     'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
     'Heterocyclic compounds',
     'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin',
     'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin having six-membered rings with one oxygen as the only ring hetero atom',
     'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin having six-membered rings with one oxygen as the only ring hetero atom condensed with carbocyclic rings, e.g. cannabinols, methantheline',
     'HUMAN NECESSITIES',
     'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
     'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
     'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
     'Hydroxy compounds, e.g. alcohols; Salts thereof, e.g. alcoholates',
     'Phenols',
     'HUMAN NECESSITIES',
     'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
     'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
     'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
     'Acids; Anhydrides, halides or salts thereof, e.g. sulfur acids, imidic, hydrazonic, hydroximic acids',
     'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid',
     'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid having an amino group',
     'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid having an amino group the amino and the carboxyl groups being attached to the same acyclic carbon chain, e.g. gamma-aminobutyric acid [GABA], beta-alanine, epsilon-aminocaproic acid, pantothenic acid',
     'Alpha-aminoacids, e.g. alanine, edetic acids [EDTA]']
```

I was able to remove repetitions by using

```
    set(my_list)
```

Or even by (to get keys from the result dictionary)

```
    from collections import Counter
    Counter(my_list)
```

But I don't have an idea how to remove values that are inside other values. Help me please with this question!

Comment: you can make 2 nested loops on the list and for each string you compare with the other, you keep track of longest one the save the results per string

Comment: How would you do it using pen and paper?

Comment: I would iterate backwards so you keep the longest first and then discard all the shorter ones, rather than have to decide to keep a short one, discard it, replace with a longer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 nested loops on the list and for each string you compare with the other, you keep track of longest one the save the results per string. It might not be an optimal solution if you have large data

Code

```
currect_list=['HUMAN NECESSITIES',
 'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
 'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
 'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
 'Heterocyclic compounds',
 'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin',
 'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin having six-membered rings with one oxygen as the only ring hetero atom',
 'Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin having six-membered rings with one oxygen as the only ring hetero atom condensed with carbocyclic rings, e.g. cannabinols, methantheline',
 'HUMAN NECESSITIES',
 'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
 'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
 'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
 'Hydroxy compounds, e.g. alcohols; Salts thereof, e.g. alcoholates',
 'Phenols',
 'HUMAN NECESSITIES',
 'MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE',
 'PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES',
 'Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients',
 'Acids; Anhydrides, halides or salts thereof, e.g. sulfur acids, imidic, hydrazonic, hydroximic acids',
 'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid',
 'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid having an amino group',
 'Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid having an amino group the amino and the carboxyl groups being attached to the same acyclic carbon chain, e.g. gamma-aminobutyric acid [GABA], beta-alanine, epsilon-aminocaproic acid, pantothenic acid',
 'Alpha-aminoacids, e.g. alanine, edetic acids [EDTA]']
 
final_resut_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(currect_list)):
 current_str=currect_list[i]
 for j in range (i+1,len(currect_list)):
    if current_str in currect_list[j] and len(currect_list[j])> len(current_str):
        current_str= currect_list[j]
 if current_str not in final_resut_list:
    final_resut_list.append(current_str)
for res in final_resut_list:
    print(res)
```

final output would be

```
HUMAN NECESSITIES
MEDICAL OR VETERINARY SCIENCE; HYGIENE
PREPARATIONS FOR MEDICAL, DENTAL, OR TOILET PURPOSES
Medicinal preparations containing organic active ingredients
Heterocyclic compounds having oxygen as the only ring hetero atom, e.g. fungichromin having six-membered rings with one oxygen as the only ring hetero atom condensed with carbocyclic rings, e.g. cannabinols, methantheline
Hydroxy compounds, e.g. alcohols; Salts thereof, e.g. alcoholates
Phenols
Acids; Anhydrides, halides or salts thereof, e.g. sulfur acids, imidic, hydrazonic, hydroximic acids
Carboxylic acids, e.g. valproic acid having an amino group the amino and the carboxyl groups being attached to the same acyclic carbon chain, e.g. gamma-aminobutyric acid [GABA], beta-alanine, epsilon-aminocaproic acid, pantothenic acid
Alpha-aminoacids, e.g. alanine, edetic acids [EDTA]
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few things:

1. You have not fully thought of this problem what happens if there is a case such as this:

`HUMAN NECESSITIES`
`HUMAN WORKS`

do you want to show the first the other, both?

Regardless, I went with assuming you want both. I implemented my solution using recursion, but as you have seen suggested, we can do this with multiple loops.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def minimize(sentences):
    word_to_sentence = defaultdict(set)
    for s in sentences:
        words = s.split(' ')
        if len(words[1:]) > 0:
            word_to_sentence[words[0]].add(" ".join(words[1:]))
    out = []
    for k, values in word_to_sentence.items():
        if len(values) > 1:
            for min_val in minimize(values):
                out.append(k + ' ' + min_val)
        else:
            out.append(k +  ' ' + list(values)[0])
    return out
print(minimize(data))
```